# Laravel Non-grouping field 'net_total' is used in HAVING clause

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have written a query that worked fine in the local server. But in production, it is not working. Here is the query.

```
Invoice::with('contact_fk','transactions')
    ->where('date','<=',$this->query_date)
    ->withSum('transactions', 'amount')
    ->havingRaw('COALESCE(transactions_sum_amount,0) < invoices.net_total')
    ->orderBy('due_date','asc');
```

The error is as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field
 'net_total' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: select sum(`net_total`) as 
 aggregate from (select `invoices`.*, (select sum(`transaction_allocations`.`amount`)
  from `transaction_allocations` where `invoices`.`id` = `transaction_allocations`.`doc_id` 
  and `transaction_allocations`.`doc_type` = App\Models\Invoice and
   `transaction_allocations`.`deleted_at` is null) as `transactions_sum_amount` from 
   `invoices` where `date` <= 2021-07-27 having COALESCE(transactions_sum_amount,0) < net_total)
    as `temp_table`)
```

A lot of suggestions online revolve around making the `'strict' => false` which is not acceptable as it avoids the issue and does not solve it.

How can I solve it? My requirement is to bring all invoices which are unpaid. Payment is stored in a separate table called `transactions`. So all invoices where `net_total` of the invoice is greater than the sum of `amount` of transactions for this invoice.

As requested including the two table structure with relevant fields. They have a polymorphic relationship. The `transaction_allocation` table contains `doc_id` and `doc_type` fields which are filled as `Apps\Models\Invoice` and `invoice_id` respectively. The name of the relationship is `transactions`.

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamps(); 
    $table->decimal('net_total',19,4);
});

Schema::create('transaction_allocations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->foreignId('transaction_id')->nullable()->constrained();
    $table->Nullablemorphs('doc');
    $table->decimal('amount',19,4)->nullable();
```

});

Comment: The structure of the query may have to change.

Comment: Show the schema (create table statements) with constraints. Some databases don't handle functional dependence even if net_total is FD on the GROUP BY terms.

Comment: I personally would opt for joins, but seems you need to either use an aggregate function in the having comparison or add an additional item in a group by clause.

Comment: I think this makes sense since you are using having without a group by which will be applied on the entire result set. You can probably do the (arguably) tedious `groupBy('id','all other fields of invoices')` to fix this